# Why does jQuery serialization not work when called through a function?

Tags: jquery, serialization

I followed the steps given in:

https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON

And it works, however, when I make this change to call the function using a button:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="title" value="Finding Loot"/>
  <input type="text" name="author[name]" value="John Smith"/>
  <input type="text" name="author[job]"  value="Legendary Pirate"/>
  <button onclick = "xyz()"> Submit </button>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

   function xyz(){
         console.log($('form').serializeJSON());
       }
</script>
```

It says serializeJSON not a function, how do I fix this?

Comment: Looks like you didn't include `jquery.serializejson.js` - or you did include it but after your code.  Can you update your question to include a working snippet that *demonstrates* the problem?  Otherwise it's just guess work.  Have a read of [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

use `jquery.serializejson.js`

then use serialize JSON function